# How can I fix CSS modules copy of styles problem?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, shopify, vite

I'm using css modules on my react app (Shopify hydrogen). I have product card component and I use it in loop to render. Problem is duplicate of styles. These components have same classnames but I see duplicate of styles. They are totally same. How can I fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnT3L.png

Loop

```js
const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="text-center mt-8">
      <div className="container">
        <SimpleGrid>
          {data.map((product, index) => (
            <ProductCard key={index} {...product} />
          ))}
        </SimpleGrid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Product Card

```js
import React from "react";
import cn from "classnames";
import styles from "./product-card.module.css";

export interface IProductCardProps {
  title: string;
  brand: string;
  image: string;
  price: number;
  lastSale?: number;
  currency?: string;
}

const ProductCard: React.FC<IProductCardProps> = ({
  title,
  brand,
  image,
  price,
  lastSale,
  currency,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.productCard}>
      <div>
        <img src={image} className={styles.productCardImage} />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.productCardContent}>
        <div className="text-sm text-gray-600">{brand}</div>
        <div className="text-md">{title}</div>
        <div className="text-lg font-semibold mt-2">
          {price} {currency}
        </div>
        <div>
          {lastSale ? (
            <div
              className={cn(
                lastSale - price > 0 ? "text-gray-500" : "text-red-500"
              )}
            >
              Last sale: {lastSale} {currency}
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ProductCard.defaultProps = {
  currency: "$",
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Css

```css
.product-card {
  @apply border
    hover:border-black;
  &__image {
    @apply w-full h-full p-8 object-contain;
  }

  &__content {
    @apply flex flex-col p-2.5;
  }
}
```

Comment: Include the code

Comment: What's your goal here? The style for each card is same, so react doesn't seem necessary to set different class names for each card.

Comment: @Engin could you please see image I added? [https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnT3L.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnT3L.png). Problem is that the duplicate of styles.

Comment: @Engin I guess that OP wants only one style tag instead of 10

Comment: Can you post the loop?

Comment: @Engin <div className="container">
        <SimpleGrid>
          {data.map((product, index) => (
            <ProductCard key={index} {...product} />
          ))}
        </SimpleGrid>
      </div>

Comment: @Engin I have also added to the post